# can't start activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I write some class (icalevent, calendermanager and icalexception) and create demo (demo is activity).  I want to test to my iCal and write this. I can't start activity and I don't understand why.

```
this.startActivity(intent());

public Intent getIntent(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);  
    intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
    intent.putExtra("title", theEvent.getName());  here is problem
    intent.putExtra("description", theEvent.getSummary()); and here

    intent.putExtra("beginTime", theEvent.getStart().getTime());and here
    intent.putExtra("endTime", theEvent.getEnd().getTime()); and here
    return intent;
}
public Intent intent(){   
    CalendarManager calandermanager = new CalendarManager();
    return calandermanager.getIntent();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The putExtra wants a different data type for that field.  Try possibly convert the time to a string?

Look here for more information on it.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,android.os.Bundle)